# How to remove a file from a "Choose file..." dialog?

Tags: forms

Or, how to set things up so users can do that, I guess...

The point: Once you've selected a managed file in a standard Drupal "Choose file..." dialog, there doesn't seem to be a way to remove the file, short of refreshing the page.  For those cases where the file is optional, something like this ought to be there, and I'm actually a little surprised that it's not there already.  I suppose I could throw some jQuery together and hang my own button off the input field, but is there really nothing in core Drupal that will do this (or IS there something, and I'm just missing it or screwing it up somehow)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are refering Drupal 7, as Drupal 8 has by default that option.

---

## D7

#### What Drupal (D7) Provides,

**Step-1:** File/Image uploading option in node.

> [image]

**Step-2:** *Example Case:* Suppose I uploaded wrong image instead of `IMG_0065.jpg`, I want to upload `IMG_0068.jpg`.

> [image]

**Step-3:** Just Re-upload the file on the previous file, the new file will be loaded and the previous file will be removed.

> [image]

**Step-4:** Image file uploaded and now als0 you can remove as Remove Button is there.

> [image]

So, In short you want **REMOVE** button at **Step-2**, But the default file uploaded do not have that option. That is the fact. But if you manage, Drupal provide the option of replacing, which is quite similar option of removing.

#### Solution using other file uploader Module

Now, instead of using Drupal's Default File uploaded feature, you can download new module called, [Drag & Drop Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload).  Installation: For this also like default file uploaded, you have to create add a field in content type and in widget option you need to choose Drag and drop instead of file.

Now, following is the image of drag and drop in action, now you can see after just browsing, you can see X mark besides file. Which is the the Step-2 option which was missing in above default setup.

> [image]

***Further Reading:*** On this link there is a detailed comparison of all type of File Uploading Modules, you can refer more from there: 
[Multiple file upload for node](https://groups.drupal.org/node/155764)

---

## D8

By default Drupal 8 has this option as shown in following image.

> [image]

Comment: Sadly, you're probably right about this (although even your example of D8 is only showing the remove button after the file has apparently been uploaded and saved).  This seems like really fundamental behavior to me -- it's not really different than removing the content of a text field before submitting the form -- and I'm kinda embarrassed that I never noticed it until now.  Anyway, I've gone the jQuery "insert a button on .change()" route, which, including validation handling and clearing, was only slightly awful.  Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 removing files occurs after you have saved a file to a Node; then you can mark it for deletion from the file list attached to a node. On Cron run the file is removed from the filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear.  I'm trying to let the user clear the input file selection *before* the form is submitted.  They select a file, realize their mistake, say "oops", and want to remove the file selection before submitting the form (and all the other work they did on it).